# How to install custom Saiku Analytics on Pentaho BI (not via Marketplace)

Tags: pentaho, saiku

We have our custom build of Saiku Analytics. How we can install it on Pentaho Bi Server? I saw one piece of advice - to place unzipped saiku-plagin to folder pentaho-solutions/system. But this method doesn't work for me. Are there any ways to solve this issue?

Excuse me for my bad English.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the good version of the plugin (that is the one compatible with the version of your BI Server), this should work.

Have you restarted your server after unzipping the plugin? When you say that it doesn't work, what do you mean : an error message in a log, on the console,...?